# Error in console when user is created via Createduserwizard

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, updatepanel, createuserwizard

I create a user via CreateUserWizard I have enclosed the CreateUserWizard in Updatepanel. When the user is created and the update is called the browser console show an error and the updatepanel is not updated.

```
    Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500 ScriptResource.axd:513


          <asp:UpdatePanel UpdateMode="Conditional"  runat="server" ID="UpdatePanelCreateUser">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server" CompleteSuccessText="Successful. Confirmation mail has been sent to the Email address. Follow the link to confirm your account."
                        DisableCreatedUser="true" LoginCreatedUser="false" OnCreatedUser="CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser"
                        OnCreatingUser="CreateUserWizard1_CreatingUser" 
                        onsendingmail="CreateUserWizard1_SendingMail1" >
                        <MailDefinition BodyFileName="~/MailFile.txt" From="spiralswhirls@yahoo.com" >

                        </MailDefinition>
                        <WizardSteps>
                            <asp:CreateUserWizardStep runat="server">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <table border="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" colspan="2">
                                                &nbsp;
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="right">
                                                <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName" Visible="false">User Name:</asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="right">
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server">First Name:</asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxFirstName"
                                                    ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="right">
                                                <asp:Label ID="LabelLastName" runat="server">Last Name:</asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxLastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxLastName"
                                                    ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="right">
                                                <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password"
                                                    ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="right">
                                                <asp:Label ID="ConfirmPasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ConfirmPassword">Confirm Password:</asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ConfirmPasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword"
                                                    ErrorMessage="Confirm Password is required." ToolTip="Confirm Password is required."
                                                    ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="right">
                                                <asp:Label ID="EmailLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Email">E-mail:</asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="EmailRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Email"
                                                    ErrorMessage="E-mail is required." ToolTip="E-mail is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="right">
                                                <asp:Label ID="LabelSex" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="DropDownListSex">Sex:</asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListSex" runat="server">
                                                    <asp:ListItem>Male</asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem>Female</asp:ListItem>
                                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DropDownListSex"
                                                    ErrorMessage="E-mail is required." ToolTip="E-mail is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="2" style="padding-left: 10px;">
                                                <BotDetect:Captcha ID="Captcha1" runat="server" CodeLength="7" />
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="280px"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <div>
                                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="LabelCaptcha" Style="font-size: 11px;"></asp:Label>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" colspan="2">
                                                <asp:CompareValidator ID="PasswordCompare" runat="server" ControlToCompare="Password"
                                                    ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="The Password and Confirmation Password must match."
                                                    ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1"></asp:CompareValidator>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color: Red;">
                                                <asp:Literal ID="ErrorMessage" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
                            <asp:CompleteWizardStep runat="server" />
                        </WizardSteps>
                    </asp:CreateUserWizard>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

the CreatedUser event

```
     protected void CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs  e)
    {
    TextBox textboxemail = (TextBox)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Email"); 
    MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(textboxemail.Text);
    Guid userid = (Guid)user.ProviderUserKey;
    TextBox firstname = (TextBox)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("TextBoxFirstName");
    TextBox lastname = (TextBox)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("TextBoxLastName");
    DropDownList sex = (DropDownList)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("DropDownListSex");
    ProfileDataAccess.SaveUserName(firstname.Text, null, lastname.Text, Convert.ToString (userid));
    ProfileDataAccess.SaveSex(sex.SelectedValue, Convert.ToString(userid));
    ProfileDataAccess.SetProfilePictureForNewUser(userid, 0);
    //CreateUserWizard1.MailDefinition.From = "autogenerated@studentjoin.com";
    Label labelCaptcha = (Label)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("LabelCaptcha");
    labelCaptcha.Text = "";
}
```

The sendingmail event

```
    protected void CreateUserWizard1_SendingMail1(object sender, MailMessageEventArgs e)
  { 
   TextBox textboxemail = (TextBox)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Email"); 
   MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(textboxemail.Text);
   Guid userid = (Guid)user.ProviderUserKey;
   string verificationurl="http://www.spiralsnet.com/Login.aspx?NewUserId="+userid.ToString ();
   e.Message.IsBodyHtml = true;
   e.Message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("SpiralsWhirls@yahoo.com", "SpiralsNet");
   e.Message.Body = e.Message.Body.Replace("<%VU%>", verificationurl);

   UpdatePanelCreateUser.Update();

}
```

}

Comment: Step into your code - specifically the `CreateUserWizard1_SendingMail1` method, as that is where you're calling the `Update()` method on the panel.  Chances are something in there threw an error, resulting in the message you got.

Comment: Thanks Tim yes I checked but every thing goes very smooth the end block breakpoint is hit without any problems.

Comment: what triggers the updatepanel to update?

Comment: Thanks @SollyM That issue has been resolved. actually there was an exception after the sendingmail had finished execution. so there is was no way to catch that exception except in Application_Error. So I moved to CreatedUserWizard and tried to send the mail manually from there and catch the exception if any to cancel the createduser manually and deleted any user created. Thanks for asking :)

Comment: Sweet. Put this as your answer then so that the article may be complete.

Answer (score 0):

issue has been resolved. actually there was an exception after the `sendingmail` had finished execution. so there  was no way to catch that exception except in `Application_Error`. So I moved to `CreatedUser` and tried to send the mail manually from there and catch the exception if any to cancel the `createduser` manually and deleted any user created.